# Antlr4: How to change my grammar to let chained elements being parsed?

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I need a grammar to parse double dots delimited tokens like:

`1..5`, `v[1]..v[2]` or `1+f(1)..2+v[f(2)]..3+f(3)`.

Basically, these tokens represent integer ranges, for ex, `1..5` means integers in range 1 to 5. Token literal should only be represented as "Integer..Integer"

I also have to parse some integer literals and real literals as well.
So currently, I have a bottom up grammar like:

```
unary_expr
  : range_expr                 # ToRangeExpr
  | PLUS rhs=unary_expr        # UnaryPlusExpr
  | MINUS rhs=unary_expr       # UnaryMinusExpr
  | NOT rhs=unary_expr         # UnaryNotExpr
  ;

range_expr
  : index_expr                             # ToIndexExpr
  | lhs=index_expr RANGEDOT rhs=index_expr # RangeExpr
  | lhs=range_literal rhs=index_expr       # RangeLiteralExpr
  ;

index_expr
  : atom                      # ToAtom
  | atom LBRACK expression RBRACK   # IndexExpr
  ;

atom
  : vector_atom               # ToVectorAtom
  | matrix_atom               # ToMatrixAtom
  | boolean_literal           # ToBooleanLiteral
  | int_literal               # ToIntegerLiteral
  | real_literal              # ToRealLiteral
  | char_literal              # ToCharLiteral
  | string_literal            # ToStringLiteral
  | tuple_literal             # ToTupleLiteral
  | range_literal             # ToRangeLiteral
  | tuple_element             # ToTupleElement
  | type_cast                 # ToTypeCast
  | stream_state              # ToStreamState
  | function_call             # ToFunctionCall
  | ID                        # IDAtom
  | IDENTITY                  # IdentityLiteral
  | NULL                      # NullLiteral
  | LPAREN expression RPAREN  # ToSubExpr


range_literal: RANGE_LITERAL;

RANGE_LITERAL
    : INT_LITERAL RANGEDOT INT_LITERAL
    ;

REAL_LITERAL
    : DOT US+ INT_LITERAL REAL_EXP?
    | INT_LITERAL DOT US* INT_LITERAL? REAL_EXP?
    | INT_LITERAL REAL_EXP
    | DOT INT_LITERAL REAL_EXP
    ;

REAL_EXP
    : 'e' US* (PLUS | MINUS |)? US* INT_LITERAL
    ;

INT_LITERAL: NUM (NUM | US)*;
```

So currently, my grammar can parse multiple-integer-chained range tokens. However, I can't parse any multiple-expression-chained range tokens. I tried to change my `range_expr` as (make it more ambiguous):

```
range_expr
  : range_literal
  | index_expr (RANGEDOT index_expr*)
  ;
```

But, it didn't change my parsing sensitivities. So what else change should I make to let my grammar parse multiple `index_expr` chained range tokens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I can't treat `range_expr` as `unary_expr` in my grammar, because it will confuse antlr4 with the `real_literal` option, and force antlr4 match `logic_expr` tokens (i.e `xor`, `or`, which I didn't show them in my question). After my micro fix, the partial grammar will be like:

```
unary_expr
  : index_expr                 # ToIndexExpr
  | PLUS rhs=unary_expr        # UnaryPlusExpr
  | MINUS rhs=unary_expr       # UnaryMinusExpr
  | NOT rhs=unary_expr         # UnaryNotExpr
  ;

index_expr
  : atom                      # ToAtom
  | atom LBRACK expression RBRACK   # IndexExpr
  | lhs=index_expr RANGEDOT rhs=index_expr  # RangeExpr
  | lhs=range_literal rhs=index_expr # RangeLiteralExpr
  ;

atom
  : vector_atom               # ToVectorAtom
  | matrix_atom               # ToMatrixAtom
  | boolean_literal           # ToBooleanLiteral
  | int_literal               # ToIntegerLiteral
  | real_literal              # ToRealLiteral
  | char_literal              # ToCharLiteral
  | string_literal            # ToStringLiteral
  | tuple_literal             # ToTupleLiteral
  | range_literal             # ToRangeLiteral
  | tuple_element             # ToTupleElement
  | type_cast                 # ToTypeCast
  | stream_state              # ToStreamState
  | function_call             # ToFunctionCall
  | ID                        # IDAtom
  | IDENTITY                  # IdentityLiteral
  | NULL                      # NullLiteral
  | LPAREN expression RPAREN  # ToSubExpr
  ;


real_literal: REAL_LITERAL     # RealLiteral
            | DOT INT_LITERAL  # EdgeCaseRealLiteral;
range_literal: RANGE_LITERAL;


RANGE_LITERAL
    : INT_LITERAL RANGEDOT
    ;

REAL_LITERAL
    : DOT US+ INT_LITERAL REAL_EXP?
    | INT_LITERAL DOT US* INT_LITERAL? REAL_EXP?
    | INT_LITERAL REAL_EXP
    | DOT INT_LITERAL REAL_EXP
    ;

REAL_EXP
    : 'e' US* (PLUS | MINUS |)? US* INT_LITERAL
    ;

INT_LITERAL: NUM (NUM | US)*;
```

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

I couldn't reuse your grammar (because of the missing lexer/parser rules) but if I understand the problem correctly: you want to have a simple range of two numbers or to chain together an arbitrary number of `expr`. Idea for this is to have a sub-rule in `index_expr` that will match range of numbers (a specialized version of `exprChain`) and to have a recursive definition of `expr` that will consist of a chaining expression (`exprChain`).

### Solution

As an example of the idea I introduce small grammar.

```antlr
grammar test;

INT : [0-9]+;
REAL : [0-9]* '.' [0-9]+;
NAME : [a-zA-Z]+;

numeric
    : INT | REAL
    ;

reference
    : NAME              # variable
    | NAME '[' expr ']' # array
    | NAME '(' expr ')' # functionCall
    ;

index_expr
    : numeric '..' numeric  # rangeOfNumbers
    | expr                  # classicExpr
    ;

expr
    : expr '+' expr   # exprAdd
    | reference       # exprRef
    | numeric         # exprNumber
    | expr '..' expr  # exprChain
    ;
```

This example grammar is able to match all the ranged expressions you mentioned: `1..5` or `.1...3` (as `rangeOfNumbers`), `v[1]..v[2]` or `1+f(1)..2+v[f(2)]..3+f(3)` (both as `exprChain`).

Comment: I should add my lexer rules too, because I also have to parse `.3` or `1.` as real literal, and `23_1` (underscore can be add after the first digit) as int literal. Your answer will not be able to parse `.3` or `1.` as real literal.

Comment: I solved the my problem by rearranging recursive definitions. I'll show you in my answer.

Comment: @LingboTang : In order to parse real numbers you need to have lexem/token for real numbers (like `REAL : [0-9]* '.' [0-9]+;`). I modified the answer.

Comment: Yes, but `[0-9]* '.' [0-9]+` will not parse `2.`, since `[0-9]+` will capture at least 1 digit rather than 0 digit. That's why I made my grammar aggressive. My current grammar can parse those cases because I got `range_literal` recursively defined in `index_expr` thanks to your inspiration.

Comment: @LingboTang : OK :)